# CIFS ver 1.0 mounting broke after update

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS as Plex server, mounting NAS shares on a Netgear ReadyNAS Ultra 6 running RAIDiator 4.2.31 using CIFS ver 1.0 (highest that my NAS will support). Had to run "sudo mount -a" after every reboot to mount the shares, which WAS working fine until I installed all updates tonight. Now I get "mount error (111): could not connect to 192.168.1.50 unable to find suitable address". I know that CIFS 1.0 is very old and unsecure, but can someone please tell me what and how to undo or fix, and most importantly how to prevent future breaks?

The mount lines in my fstab are: //192.168.1.50/movies /mnt/movies cifs credentials=/etc/nascred,vers=1.0 0 0

I've tried changing the vers= to 1.1, 1.2 & 2.0 with no luck.

Comment: You've not provided OS & particularly release details.

Comment: https://community.netgear.com/t5/Using-your-ReadyNAS-in-Business/How-to-modify-samba-config-with-raidiator-4-2-31/m-p/1845347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMB1 has been disabled for security reasons. Let's re-enable SMB1 for your NAS requirements.

Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf...

Locate the section that starts with:

```
#### Networking ####
```

Add the following to re-enable SMB1:

```
# allow SMB1
client min protocol = NT1
server min protocol = NT1
name resolve order = bcast host lmhosts wins
```

Restart smbd and nmbd services.

Comment: Hi & thank you very much for your generous & straight forward answer.  That sounds like exactly what has happened, and I copied/pasted those 4 lines into the /etc/samba/smb.conf file, saved and rebooted the entire system.  I still receive the same error, did a system restart not restart the services?  If so, is there anyway to tell exactly what update broke it so that we might downgrade it?

Comment: @Turp See if `findsmb` and `smbtree` commands work to find your NAS.

Comment: I also should've mentioned that I can ping my NAS's IP address but not it's name.  The findsmb lists it, but the smbtree prompts for the workgroup password but won't accept the share password.

Comment: @Turp You may have more wrong than just SMB1 being disabled. SMB1 must be working now, as the `findsmb` and `smbtree` wouldn't work without it. The Workgroup password wouldn't be the same as the share password. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: You're probably right, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Turp Look at `systemctl status smbd` and `systemctl status nmbd` for more info.

Comment: Hi everyone!  So, I'm not sure at all what happened, but I'm pretty sure that heynnema's answer did in fact correct my Linux mounting issue, and then mysteriously overnight something happened on my NAS which made the shares available again. No idea what (cause it doesn't autoupdate), but I'm certainly not complaining. I also noticed that the NAS icon in Windows explorer under Network is different/newer looking, so.  Anyway, thank you all for your knowledge and help!!  You're really awesome the way you help people.

Comment: @Turp After rebooting, or restarting smbd/nmbd, it takes a while for Samba to fully come up. Maybe you just needed to give it a little more time... :-) Good news!

Comment: A curious solution to a cifs mount problem since mount.cifs doesn't reference smb.conf on the client. It's Linux kernel based and doesn't even know smb.conf exists.