# Cannot mout old NAS on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mount, 22.04, samba, cifs

I have an old NAS, a Synology CS407, which I want to mount on my Ubuntu server running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
However, I cannot succeed in mounting it.

I have tried mounting it with NFS and SMB/CIFS, but both don't work. I would like to use SMB, as it has authentication.
This particular NAS only supports SMB version 1 I think.

Anyway, I've tried to mount using the following command, receiving this error:

```
mount.cifs //192.168.1.201/volume1/folder1 /mnt/cifs/folder1 -o vers=1.0,user=admin
mount error(6): No such device or address
```

It says to look at `dmesg`, which says:

```
Use of the less secure dialect vers=1.0 is not recommended unless required for access to very old servers

CIFS: VFS: Use of the less secure dialect vers=1.0 is not recommended unless required for access to very old servers
CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.1.201/volume1/folder1
CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -6
```

I have seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1361645/1765475) question already, but it didn't help me.

Any help is appreciated!

Ps. I know SMB1 is very old and insecure; should I just toss the NAS away and get a newer one, or can it still be used?

#### EDIT 1

`smbclient -L //192.168.1.201 -U admin` returns the following:

```
Password for [WORKGROUP\admin]:

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        home            Disk      home
        folder1         Disk      share1
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service ()
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.

        Server               Comment
        ---------            -------

        Workgroup            Master
        ---------            -------
        WORKGROUP
```

Comment: It would be useful to verify that share and user are correct and accessible with `smbclient -L //192.168.1.201 -U admin`

Comment: Is `/volume1/folder1` really the name of the share that is exported by NAS?
As far as I remember, if you export a share via SMB, you give it a single-level name, and you can only mount the whole share, not a subdirectory if it.
Try `mount //192.168.1.201/volume1` (or `mount //192.168.1.201/folder1`) only.

Comment: Thank you @raj!, that was it, I mounted with `/folder1`. I was confused because mounting with NFS you _do_ need to provide the volume. Please make it an answer, then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exported SMB shares are identified with only single-level names, not multi-level names like `/volume1/folder1` (contrary to NFS, where full path is used to identify the exported directory). So you shouldn't use `mount //192.168.1.201/volume1/folder1`, try to use `mount //192.168.1.201/volume1` or `mount //192.168.1.201/folder1` instead.